# scrollToVisible not working in while scrolling a tableview in iOS UIAutomation

Tags: ios, ui-automation, ios-ui-automation

I am writing scripts for `UIAutomation` in iOS. I am recording a `UITableView` scrolling through Instruments but when I run the same recorded script then it does not scroll the `view`.

It calls "scrollToVisible" call to scroll. For example:

`target.frontMostApp().mainWindow().scrollViews()[0].tableViews()[0].cells()[3].scrollToVisible();`

Though, it doesn't scroll it and hence gives error in tapping this element. Why is it happening?

Answer (score 0):

Try to check if an element you are trying to manipulate isValid or/and isVisible before calling the scrollToVisible()

```
   var cellToScroll = target.frontMostApp().mainWindow().scrollViews()[0].tableViews()[0].cells()[3];

   if ( cellToScroll.checkIsValid() )
    {
        if (!cellToScroll.isVisible() )
        {
             cellToScroll.scrollToVisible();
        }
     // do other actions with object
    }
    else
    {
        UIALogger.logMessage("object is invalid");
    }
```

Also Sometimes recorder captures elements that are not visible. For example you have 2 views. View1 and View2. View1 has scrollView>table>cells. View2 has some nonAccessible elements. View2 is displayed over the view1. In this case recorder will ignore View2 and will capture view1 elements. 
In this case running the script will give the same error. checkIsValid() will return true, isVisible() will return false and script will fail on cellToScroll.scrollToVisible() with the same error; In this case you will need to do some additional verifications like - is View2 is visible or something like this.

Answer (score -1):

I know this was asked a while ago, but the code above won't work. This is because isVisible() returns a number and not a boolean. To see if the cell is visible on the page, you would have to check and see if isVisible() returns a 1:

```
if (cellToScroll.isVisible() == 1 )
{
    cellToScroll.scrollToVisible();
}
```

Comment: it doesn't matter, if (0) won't execute but if (1) will